# pandas series string path replace

Tags: pandas

I have a pandas dataframe with multiple columns. The entries corresponding to one column are strings that represent paths to pictures stored on my machine e.g.

```
df["image_files"][df.index[0]]
df["image_files"][df.index[1]]
.
.
.
```

will print

```
'/home/user_name/Desktop/folder_name_1/folder_name_2/image_name_1.jpeg'
'/home/user_name/Desktop/folder_name_1/folder_name_2/image_name_2.jpeg'
.
.
.
```

I would like to replace a part of this string everywhere in the series s.t. e.g.

```
df["image_files"][df.index[0]]
df["image_files"][df.index[1]]
.
.
.
```

would print

```
'./new_folder_name_1/new_folder_name_2/image_name_1.jpeg'
'./new_folder_name_1/new_folder_name_2/image_name_2.jpeg'
.
.
.
```

Basically I want `/home/user_name/Desktop/folder_name_1/folder_name_2/` to be replaced with `./new_folder_name_1/new_folder_name_2/` everywhere. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, replace the string in series column.

```
df["image_files"] = df["image_files"].str.replace("/home/user_name/Desktop/folder_name_1/folder_name_2/","./new_folder_name_1/new_folder_name_2/")
```